# VBA Find Pattern Word file and export every two pages as .pdf

Tags: vba, ms-word, export-to-pdf

I have Word file (154 pages). I need to take every 2 pages and export as .pdf (I did this), but I need also to add file name like EExxxxxxxx (patern), I set reg pattern like "(EE[0-9]{8})" it's ok in my opinion, because it find the first pattern, always EE and 8 numbers (examples below). The same pattern are on every two pages. I can't get it from this two pages, and add this value as file name, because I get only the first pattern (and script finish searching, when I go to next 2 pages inside Word file), but the same time next files (with 2 right pages) are creating.
Of cource every pages have a lot of different text, but the paterns are the most important.

Word File: 
Page 1:EE30000229 
Page 2:EE30000229 
Page 3:EE30000089 
Page 4:EE30000089 
... 
Page 153: EE30001889 
Page 154: EE30001889

Script1:

```
Option Explicit
Sub SaveAsSeparatePDFs()
 
Dim strDirectory As String, strTemp As String
Dim ipgStart As Integer, ipgEnd As Integer
Dim iPDFnum As Integer, i As Integer
Dim vMsg As Variant, bError As Boolean
Dim Name As String
Dim RegEx As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
Set RegEx = New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
Dim Matches As VBScript_RegExp_55.matchCollection
Dim Match As VBScript_RegExp_55.Match


1:
strDirectory = InputBox("Directory to save individual PDFs? " & _
    vbNewLine & "(ex: C:\Users\Public)")
If strDirectory = "" Then Exit Sub
If Dir(strDirectory, vbDirectory) = "" Then
    vMsg = MsgBox("Please enter a valid directory.", vbOKCancel, "Invalid Directory")
    If vMsg = 1 Then
        GoTo 1
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If

2:
strTemp = InputBox("Begin saving PDFs starting with page __? " & _
    vbNewLine & "(ex: 32)")
bError = bErrorF(strTemp)
If bError = True Then GoTo 2
ipgStart = CInt(strTemp)

3:
strTemp = InputBox("Save PDFs until page __?" & vbNewLine & "(ex: 37)")
bError = bErrorF(strTemp)
If bError = True Then GoTo 3
ipgEnd = CInt(strTemp)

iPDFnum = ipgStart
On Error GoTo 4:

 
For i = ipgStart To ipgEnd Step 2
    
   '-- This code creating .pdf includes every two pages. But I need add some code that give to me also
   '-- right file name with EExxxxxxxx and exchange iPDFnum that is below
    ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
        strDirectory & "\Page_" & iPDFnum & ".pdf", ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, _
        OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:= _
        wdExportFromTo, From:=i, to:=i + 1, Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, _
        IncludeDocProps:=False, KeepIRM:=False, CreateBookmarks:= _
        wdExportCreateHeadingBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
        BitmapMissingFonts:=False, UseISO19005_1:=False
    iPDFnum = iPDFnum + 2
   
Next i
End

End
4:
vMsg = MsgBox("Unknown error encountered while creating PDFs." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
    "Aborting", vbCritical, "Error Encountered")
End Sub

Private Function bErrorF(strTemp As String) As Boolean
Dim i As Integer, vMsg As Variant
bErrorF = False

If strTemp = "" Then
    End
ElseIf IsNumeric(strTemp) = True Then
    i = CInt(strTemp)
    If i > ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties(wdPropertyPages) Or i <= 0 Then
        Call msgS(bErrorF)
    End If
Else
    Call msgS(bErrorF)
End If
End Function

Private Sub msgS(bMsg As Boolean)
Dim vMsg As Variant
    vMsg = MsgBox("Please enter a valid integer." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        "Integer must be > 0 and < total pages in the document (" & _
        ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties(wdPropertyPages) & ")", vbOKCancel, "Invalid Integer")
    If vMsg = 1 Then
        bMsg = True
    Else
        End
    End If
End Sub
```

The next Sub, that can show all of the patterns (EExxxxxxxx) from Word file. I don't now how to add these two scripts so that they generate files contain 2 more pages from the Word file and their name includes the EExxxxxxxx template. I change .Global also with True, but still show only the first pattern from the list.

Script2:

```
 Sub Find()
 Dim RegEx As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
 Set RegEx = New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
 Dim Matches As VBScript_RegExp_55.matchCollection
 Dim Match As VBScript_RegExp_55.Match
    
 With RegEx
     .IgnoreCase = False
     .MultiLine = True
     .Global = False    
     .Pattern = "(EE[0-9]{8})"
 End With
 Set Matches = RegEx.Execute(ActiveDocument.Content.Text)
 For Each Match In Matches
     MsgBox (Match.Value)
 Next Match

End Sub
```

Anyone can help to me? It's important project to my organisation.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need RegEx to do this. Word's built-in Find function can be used with wildcards to match patterns. The function below will return the text matching your pattern if found on the specified page.

```
Function FindPattern(pageNum As Long) As String
    Dim rngFind As Range
    Set rngFind = ActiveDocument.GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, Name:=pageNum)
    Set rngFind = rngFind.GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\Page")
    With rngFind.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "EE[0-9]{8}"
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        If .Execute Then FindPattern = rngFind.Text
    End With
End Function
```

You would use it inside your loop, for example:

```
For i = ipgStart To ipgEnd Step 2
    text = FindPattern(i)
```

EDIT:
Code used for testing

```
Sub SaveAsSeparatePDFs()
 
    Dim strDirectory As String, strTemp As String
    Dim ipgStart As Integer, ipgEnd As Integer
    Dim iPDFnum As Integer, i As Long
    Dim vMsg As Variant, bError As Boolean
    Dim Name As String, patternText As String

1:
    strDirectory = InputBox("Directory to save individual PDFs? " & _
            vbNewLine & "(ex: C:\Users\Public)")
    If strDirectory = "" Then Exit Sub
    If Dir(strDirectory, vbDirectory) = "" Then
            vMsg = MsgBox("Please enter a valid directory.", vbOKCancel, "Invalid Directory")
            If vMsg = 1 Then
                  GoTo 1
            Else
                  Exit Sub
            End If
    End If

2:
    strTemp = InputBox("Begin saving PDFs starting with page __? " & _
            vbNewLine & "(ex: 32)")
    bError = bErrorF(strTemp)
    If bError = True Then GoTo 2
    ipgStart = CInt(strTemp)

3:
    strTemp = InputBox("Save PDFs until page __?" & vbNewLine & "(ex: 37)")
    bError = bErrorF(strTemp)
    If bError = True Then GoTo 3
    ipgEnd = CInt(strTemp)

    iPDFnum = ipgStart
    On Error GoTo 4:

 
    For i = ipgStart To ipgEnd Step 2
        patternText = FindPattern(i)
           '-- This code creating .pdf includes every two pages. But I need add some code that give to me also
           '-- right file name with EExxxxxxxx and exchange iPDFnum that is below
            ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
                  strDirectory & "\Page_" & iPDFnum & ".pdf", ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, _
                  OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:= _
                  wdExportFromTo, From:=i, to:=i + 1, Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, _
                  IncludeDocProps:=False, KeepIRM:=False, CreateBookmarks:= _
                  wdExportCreateHeadingBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
                  BitmapMissingFonts:=False, UseISO19005_1:=False
            iPDFnum = iPDFnum + 2
   
    Next i
    End

    End
4:
    vMsg = MsgBox("Unknown error encountered while creating PDFs." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
            "Aborting", vbCritical, "Error Encountered")
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks, but after I'm starting it, inside "for loop" with function even I'm on 3th page function still getting pattern from page number 1 and 2 not from 3th. Every two pages I have the same pattern, but they are of course different on next pages.   So when I generate files the are override.

Comment: @czaki249 - I tested it using your code and it works perfectly for me.

Comment: could you please paste the version that you tested?

Comment: @czaki249 - see edited answer